# View not following it's height

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following view, it's basically an `ImageView`, some content (within the `ImageView`) on the top and some content at the bottom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/girgio" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/uppercontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_up_selector"
        android:padding="4dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/favbtn"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="test"
            android:textAppearance="@style/LargeTextBold"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lowercontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_down_selector"
        android:padding="8dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/priceLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pricevalue"
                android:text="2000$"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="@style/LargeTextBold"
                android:textColor="@color/mygreen"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Preis"
                android:textAppearance="@style/SmallText"
                android:textColor="@color/mygreylight" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/areaLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/priceLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/areavalue"
                android:text="100m"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="@style/LargeTextBold"
                android:textColor="@color/mygreen"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Größe"
                android:textAppearance="@style/SmallText"
                android:textColor="@color/mygreylight" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:text="New York"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/areaLayout"
            android:textAppearance="@style/LargeTextBold"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This works fine when I use the layout in a `ListView` (via an adapter):

[image]

But when I use the same layout and add it to a `HorizontalScrollView` or within a `ViewPager`, the view doesn't adhere to the height set in it's root layout (240dp):

[image]

Why could this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't understand how relativeLayout works. You Layout is too hard and will work slow in list.
First of all, this code:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/favbtn"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="test"
        android:textAppearance="@style/LargeTextBold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

you can replace with this:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:kayout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/favbtn"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="test"
        android:textAppearance="@style/LargeTextBold"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_up_selector"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

And it will be more simple and works like your.

About your problem.
You can't use alignParentBottom inside RelativeLayout with height=wrap_content. It will cause different behavior in different case. When you building it inside listView, it will have exact height and everything fine. When you using it inside LinearLayout (or viewPager with horizontal scrolling) it will fill parents height (because android donn't know how to measure it height, when elements start to draw at bottom). To fix your problem, set height of parent relativeLayout to 240dp (like image inside) and it will work fine.

But I suggest you to read about best practices in android interface. You are using a lot of unnecesary layouts. You can put all really can remove all of your relative layouts except one (the parent one). And also remove all of your LinearLayouts.

Comment: I know it looks like lots of the layouts are unneccesary but they aren't, I left some stuff out for better readability (the outcome still being the same). 
Setting the height of the RelativeLayout id:root worked though, thanks.

Comment: I glad to help you. But i'm sure, that most of them are unneccesary. I have wrote a lot of layouts, but I have never used relativeLayout inside RelativeLayout. It's unneccesary in 99% cases.